# Scraping data from JS widget with Python

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm working on a data analytics project and want to read real time data feeds of stock prices. I found a free JS widget which can be embedded on websites (https://www.dukascopy.com/trading-tools/widgets/charts/chart) with the below code. Is there a way to tap into this with Python and read the data in real time? I could get the data with an infinite loop which sends a request every second or so, but this is very inefficient especially when keeping track of multiple instruments.

Snippet provided by the service:

```
<script type="text/javascript">DukascopyApplet = {"type":"chart","params":{"showUI":true,"showTabs":true,"showParameterToolbar":true,"showOfferSide":true,"allowInstrumentChange":true,"allowPeriodChange":true,"allowOfferSideChange":true,"showAdditionalToolbar":true,"showDetachButton":true,"presentationType":"candle","axisX":true,"axisY":true,"legend":true,"timeline":true,"showDateSeparators":true,"showZoom":true,"showScrollButtons":true,"showAutoShiftButton":true,"crosshair":true,"borders":false,"theme":"Pastelle","uiColor":"#000","availableInstruments":"l:","instrument":"EUR/USD","period":"7","offerSide":"BID","timezone":0,"live":true,"panLock":false,"width":"100%","height":"600","adv":"popup"}};</script><script type="text/javascript" src="https://freeserv-static.dukascopy.com/2.0/core.js"></script>
```

Comment: Well, their API documentation is [here](https://www.dukascopy.com/trading-tools/api/documentation/quotes). They are asking for an [application](https://www.dukascopy.com/trading-tools/api/apply) before providing you the _key_ so you can use their API easily.

Comment: Also, there's a [disclaimer](https://www.dukascopy.com/trading-tools/disclaimer) stating that: _[...] such data reflect the current fair value of the respective financial instruments as independently assessed by Dukascopy Bank SA and NOT the actual values at a given point in time. If you are looking to obtain actual quotes please contact the respective entities that provide this information._